# Unable to distinguish the meaning of two sentences which have words placed in different positions

Tags: translation, sentence-structure, german-to-english, verb-usage

1. What is the difference between the following two sentences.
   Google translate is showing different meaning for them.

Sent 1: Sie ist letzten Monat schon drei geworden

Sent 2: Sie ist letzten schon drei Monat geworden

2. Can anyone please explain to me how the position of Monat will change the meaning?
3. Also is there any impact if we place letzten to some other position like after drei?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: _"Sie ist letzten schon drei Monat geworden"_ Doesn't make any sense. _letzten_ refers to what exactly? _drei Monat_ should be plural (_drei Monate_), nay?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second sentence is wrong, or at least incomplete.

The first sentence translates to something like "She already turned three (years old) last month". The expression of time can be placed in German like you see in the sentence. You might say, the sentence divides up this way

> Sie | ist | letzten Monat | schon | drei (Jahre alt) | geworden.

The second sentence would verbatim translate to something like "She already turned three month last". As you see, the age would need to be in plural ("drei Monate" instead of "drei Monat"). Also, the expression of time is incomplete (last *what*?)

A complete sentence might look like this: "Sie ist letzten Dienstag schon drei Monate geworden", "She already turned three months last Tuesday".

As you see, both the first sentence and the (completed) second one have significantly different meanings.

Comment: Or maybe *letztens, letzthin* if you don't want to add a noun like *Dienstag* for the second sentence.

Comment: @Henning Kockerbeck, I agree that it should be Monate, that makes sense and yes, the second sentence is not correct.(Now i understand why)
and is there any rule related to where letzten should be placed?
also what is the verb form of letzthin and how does it replace Dienstag?

Comment: @akshitbhatia I'm not aware of a formal rule where to put the expression of time. "letzthin" is a (quite old-fashioned) adverb of time that basically means "recently". More current synonymes would be "letztens" or "demletzt". David Vogt basically suggested to change "last _something_" to "recently" so you wouldn't need a specific _something_ ;)